# ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'Return'

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

The error pops up whenever I try to compile through truffle, not able to figure out a solution any help is highly appreciated.
Here is the error

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/OraclizeTest.sol

Error: CompileError: /root/Latest->querytransaction Working  GOLD/oraclize-test/contracts/OraclizeTest.sol:36:9: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'Return'
        return true;
        ^
```

Here is the solidity file

```
 function deposit(uint team) public payable returns(bool success) {
        if(team == 1)
        {
        homeBet = msg.sender;
        amountStore[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit LogDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value, "Executed deposit HOME");
        oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://api.crowdscores.com/v1/matches/123945?api_key=93c4c515196741beaf5e4528b64ea511).outcome.winner");
        return true;
        }
        else if(team == 2)      
        {
        awayBet = msg.sender;                //---->> LINE NUMBER 36
        amountStore[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit LogDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value, "Executed deposit AWAY");
        oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://api.crowdscores.com/v1/matches/123945?api_key=93c4c515196741beaf5e4528b64ea511).outcome.winner");
        return true; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of each call to `oraclize_query`. This is conclusively a low-quality question!

Comment: I am using the sublime editor to code and it doesnt provides a good view for parenthesis, any help or suggestion on what you use for code indentation and editor? I finally also learned why it was pointing the error like this and what it means Thank you